Set properties of an exe using Golang
Here's what I have so far:
package main 

import (
"os"
"github.com/saferwall/pe"
)
func main(){
    exePath, _:= os.Executable()
    peFile, _:= pe.New(exePath, &pe.Options{})
    peFile.Parse()
    peFile.Anomalies = []string{"some sample anomalies", "other sample anomalies"}

//how do I write the values back to the original exe file? 
}

I want the Anomalies values to be accessible the next time I access the exe in the same way shown above.
Solutions that alter properties other than Anomalies are also great. I just picked Anomalies because it's a []string.
Any ideas? Thanks!

Looking at the github.com/saferwall/pe library, it seems to be for analyzing files rather than creating them. Looking through the GoDoc I don't see any option to write the file. So it seems this library may not support your needs.

@phonaputer thanks for looking through it. Do you know another way to write to the file? Also, just to clarify, I don't want to create a file. I want to set the properties of the file associated with the path.

Unfortunately I don't. I've not worked with Portable Executables before, and a Google search does not seem to turn up any Go libraries for creating them. I can say that it is possible to create arbitrary files using the os package, but I think that's not too useful without a library for generating executables in the PE format.
